# Get Data info from a certain page- MediaWiki API

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I'm  very new to the api system and i was wondering how to get data from a certain page. So my link is:

https://nookipedia.com/w/api.php

but i want to get my api from this page:

https://nookipedia.com/wiki/Bugs/Animal_Crossing:_New_Leaf

but when i try this:

```
https://nookipedia.com/wiki/Bugs/Animal_Crossing:_New_Leaf/w/api.php
```

the link doesn't work and gives me this error:

```
Error 404: Not found

The requested page or file could not be found on our server. It may have been moved or deleted.
```

How would i get that certain page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you play around with the [API sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox) on Wikipedia to see how queries are built. You will still need to read the [actual API documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) to get useful information...

Basically, you want to pass the title(s) as a parameter to `api.php`, like so:

```
https://nookipedia.com/w/api.php?titles=Bugs/Animal_Crossing:_New_Leaf
```

However, this will still get you no information by itself; you need to know **what** data you want exactly, and use the correct API module with the appropriate parameters. For example, to get all the categories of a page:

```
https://nookipedia.com/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Bugs/Animal_Crossing:_New_Leaf&prop=categories
```

For this specific example, you can see the documentation for the Query API and the Categories property:

- [API:Query](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query)
- [API:Categories](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categories)